# How can I pass user-defined variable into MySQL Database Table using C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, variables

I have created MySQL Database, I would like to add user-defined variables(age and grade) into the database table. I couldn't figure out how to include variables into the table in my database. 
The code is pasted below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MYSQL* conn;
    conn = mysql_init(0);
    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "127.0.0.1", "root", "password", "test", 0, NULL, 0);


    if (conn)
    {
        cout << "Connected" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Not Connected";


    int grade;
    int age;
    cout << "Enter Age and Grade" << endl;
    cin >> age;
    cin >> grade;



    mysql_query(conn, "CREATE TABLE test1 ( AGE INT, GRADE INT)");

    mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO test (AGE, GRADE) VALUES (age, grade)"; //I am asking about this part




    mysql_close(conn);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking for an answer (there can be syntax mistake, due to stack overflow indentation system).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
MYSQL* conn;
conn = mysql_init(0);
conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "127.0.0.1", "root", "password", "test", 0, NULL, 0);


if (conn)
{
    cout << "Connected" << endl;
}
else
    cout << "Not Connected";


string name;
string city;
cout << "Enter name and city: " << endl;
cin >> name;
cin >> city;



mysql_query(conn, "CREATE TABLE test1 ( NAME VARCAR (50), CITY CARCHAR (50)");

mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO test ('NAME', 'CITY') VALUES ('"+age+"', 
'"+grade+"'))";


mysql_close(conn);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with the MySQL library, but according to their documentation for the function you are using, I think you should simply create a function that creates a statement that you can format to your liking. You could use [sprintf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/).